# number of induced subgraph for a prime number $p$

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

For a graph $G$ and a prime number $p$, show that the number of induced subgraphs, that $p|deg(v)$ for each vertex of these subgraphs, is divisible by $p$.

I wanted to use Chevalley-Warning theorem, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This seems false for $G = K_{p+1}$. The only induced subgraphs with this property are $K_{p+1}$ itself and (if you count them) the $p+1$ subgraphs with only one vertex. Neither $1$ nor $p+2$ is divisible by $p$, so what am I missing?

Comment: Could you explain more please.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Maybe count the *empty graph* too. Still a counterexample though.

Comment: @mhf He demonstrated that you cannot prove it because it is not true. What do you need explanation on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is false such that Misha Lavrov said.

But I think this is true for just $p=2$. Because suppose $A$ is the incidence matrix of graph $G$ in $\mathbb{z}_2$. any vector in $ker(A)$ is a $\{0,1\}$ vector. That means we choose some edges which this number is even. We know $dim(ker(A))=m-n+c$, where $m, n, c$ is the number of edges, vertices and connected component, respectively. This is a famous result that there exists $m-n+c$ cycles in $G$ such that their corresponding vectors form a basis for $ker(A)$. So it is obvious that the union of some of these cycles in $ker(A)$ and conversely. The number of it is $2^{m-n+c}$. This is even.